# how to scrape a <script type = "text / javascript"> tag in php?

Tags: javascript, php

1. my question is how can I scrape this tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var BCData = {"csrf_token":"686611cabde717e63c8ad811ac28ff1a2566168df14ec1439799dbfc0569f2c8","product_attributes":{"purchasable":true,"purchasing_message":null,"sku":"STICKER_PACK","upc":null,"stock":null,"instock":true,"stock_message":null,"weight":null,"base":false,"image":null,"price":{"without_tax":{"formatted":"$3.99","value":3.99,"currency":"USD"},"tax_label":"Tax"},"out_of_stock_behavior":"label_option","out_of_stock_message":"Out of stock","available_modifier_values":[],"available_variant_values":[7375],"in_stock_attributes":[7375],"selected_attributes":[]}};
</script>
```

2. what I want to extract is the value of csrf_token or `686611cabde717e63c8ad811ac28ff1a2566168df14ec1439799dbfc0569f2c8`
3. I already tried as below but did not get the result I expected

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, '$url');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("accept-language: es-419,es;q=0.9"));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

```
preg_match_all('(<script type="text/javascript">
var BCData = {"csrf_token":\"(.*)\","product_attributes":{"purchasable":true,"purchasing_message":null,"sku":"STICKER_PACK","upc":null,"stock":null,"instock":true,"stock_message":null,"weight":null,"base":false,"image":null,"price":{"without_tax":{"formatted":"$3.99","value":3.99,"currency":"USD"},"tax_label":"Tax"},"out_of_stock_behavior":"label_option","out_of_stock_message":"Out of stock","available_modifier_values":[],"available_variant_values":[7375],"in_stock_attributes":[7375],"selected_attributes":[]}};</script>)siU', $result, $matches1);
$titulo = $matches1[1][0];
echo $titulo;
```

4. I can't get the result

Comment: Why are you scraping content for CSRF token data? This seems suspicious to me, skilled developers spend their lives designing security measures like CSRF tokens. You are asking for help to scrape the data...? @user1597430 below is correct though, that regex will extract the token

Comment: @Prof83 scraping the CSRF token after a request you make is not a security issue. The security issue is getting someone else's CSRF token. If you're getting your own token from a request you made it's fine

Comment: Yes that is correct, but its still suspicious from a bot perspective. Give a bot a user account (who is supposed to be a human) and scrape CSRF token data to get up to no good is usually the motive

Comment: @Prof83 Actually it's a lot more common than you'd think in automation scenarios. Of course one needs to be extremely careful not to be violating any terms of service on the page being scraped and one should always prefer to use an API if one is available, but this being said, there's many legitimate reasons as to why you'd want to do this

Comment: My sentiments exactly. If the OP can say something on these lines about their reasons, I'm not suspicious anymore

Comment: @Jonn please give us a minimal sample of the returned html document so that we can show you how to properly parse the document (with a DOM parser), then isolate and parse the js variable's json string, then extract your targeted value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781028/2943403

Answer (score 1):

You can probably grab the variable BCData and then convert it into JSON:

```php
$data = preg_match_all('/var\s+BCData\s*=\s*({.*?});/m', $result , $matches);
if (!empty($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[1][0])) {
   $data = json_decode($matches[1][0], true);
   echo $data['csrf_token'];
}
```

This assumes that the code will have a JSON valid value within the script tag, which seems to be true now, but may not be true forever.

[Sandbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/369eaafdd3b44c42b221413617e9cdc01a6e896c)

Comment: The best approach IMO

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is pointless -- there are no anchors in the expression.  I don't know why everyone is using `preg_match_all()`.  I wouldn't use a capture group.  The `empty()` calls can removed by simply checking for a truthy return from the preg call.  Your demo decodes into an array (correctly).  Your answer decodes into an object (incorrectly).   For these reasons  @Prof this is NOT "the best approach".  Maybe I better stop waiting for the perfect question and just post an answer.

Comment: We are using preg_match_all because the OP first used _all. We cannot assume why and since its not part of the original question, it was left that way. The capture group is helpful - I indicated that this is a best approach for reasons that apokryfos highlighted the importance of rather decoding the JSON data.

Comment: @mickmackusa the `m` pattern modifier was more to also capture the JSON in case it was "pretty printed"

Comment: Then you want `s`.

Comment: @apo the `s` pattern modifier will tell the dot metacharacter (any character) to include newline characters while matching any character.  The `m` pattern modifier will tell `^` and `$` metacharacters (anchors) to match beginning and end of lines instead of the default beginning/end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

For reliability, the whole html document should be parsed by a DOM parser to isolate the `<script>` node.

Then use regex to carve out the json string.  The `m` modifier makes `^` match the start of a line and `$` match the end of a line. `\K` restarts the fullstring match so that no capture groups are needed.

Then, for reliability, parse the json string and access the desired value by key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ulfdE))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
var BCData = {"csrf_token":"686611cabde717e63c8ad811ac28ff1a2566168df14ec1439799dbfc0569f2c8","product_attributes":{"purchasable":true,"purchasing_message":null,"sku":"STICKER_PACK","upc":null,"stock":null,"instock":true,"stock_message":null,"weight":null,"base":false,"image":null,"price":{"without_tax":{"formatted":"$3.99","value":3.99,"currency":"USD"},"tax_label":"Tax"},"out_of_stock_behavior":"label_option","out_of_stock_message":"Out of stock","available_modifier_values":[],"available_variant_values":[7375],"in_stock_attributes":[7375],"selected_attributes":[]}};
</script>
HTML;

echo preg_match(
         '~^var BCData = \K.*(?=;$)~m',
         $html,
         $match
     )
     ? json_decode($match[0])->csrf_token
     : 'pattern found no match';
```

Output:

```
686611cabde717e63c8ad811ac28ff1a2566168df14ec1439799dbfc0569f2c8
```

Admittedly, I don't know how the input string may vary so I can only build a pattern for the string provided.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest expression to extract the CSRF from the page:

```
# matches all occurrences of the format of the CSRF token
if (preg_match_all('/[a-f0-9]{64}/', $string, $matches))
{
    # should equal the value of the transmitted CSRF
    print_r($matches[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: This will not be a robust, reliable way to extract the targeted data from the returned html document.

Comment: @mickmackusa, scrappers are not reliable by design because you never know who and when would change the HTML structure on the page. OP can always improve this answer by adding the surrounding data. However, his main problem - he doesn't know how to write RegExp expressions. So a simple sample would be much better for education purposes than a long monster he doesn't know how to write.

Comment: My point is that your recommended pattern does not attempt to qualify the string as being part of the js declaration.  It will match ANY string composed of [a-f\d] which has a length of 64 or more.  This may likely be the lightest pattern on the page, but it is also the most prone to false positive matching which is harder to catch as a developer.  Other patterns/answers that are more strict will be more likely to result in false negatives (no match), but these failures are naturally much easier for a developer to catch/identify/repair.

Answer (score 0):

This specifically matches multiple instances of the `"csrf_token":"..."` portion of the JSON and extracts the token value in a named group

```
// Match all occurrences
if (preg_match_all('/\"csrf_token\"\s?\:\s?\"(?<csrf>[a-f0-9]{64})\"/', $string, $matches)) {

    // One or more token matches extracted from the JSON
    print_r($matches['csrf']);

}
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of only using on regex for this task -- it is potentially unreliable to parse an html document with regex.

Comment: I agree, but this is a lot more specific: `"csrf_token": "a-f0-9{64}"`

Comment: That pattern is far more likely to fail. That will fail to match the sample string. Do you see why?

Comment: The pattern works, [see this test](https://regex101.com/r/HzGI81/2)

Comment: That is a different pattern than you commented.

Comment: @mickmackusa the comment contains a pseudo pattern, the answer contains the actual pattern