# Return JSON Object with certain name

Tags: php, json

I find this quite hard to explain as you can see in the title but let's say this is how my object looks like,

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "name":"Stick",
         "value":"wood",
         "size":"large"
      }...
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to get all the data where the objects name is Stick, so basically if it's "name" is stick it should return, name, value and size.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Comment: @Samhakadas it's impossible without a foreach loop..? I hate doing multiple foreach loops inside each other :( Just feels bad.

Comment: Thanks I got it working annyways