# How to fetch data from json string using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json string and I want to fetch product data from this string How can I achieve this. Please some one help me.

Below is my string,

```
{"num_rows":2,"row":{"setting":"a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Featutred\";s:7:\"product\";a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"145\";i:1;s:3:\"148\";}s:5:\"limit\";s:1:\"5\";s:5:\"width\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"height\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"status\";s:1:\"1\";}"},"rows":[{"setting":"a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Featutred\";s:7:\"product\";a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"145\";i:1;s:3:\"148\";}s:5:\"limit\";s:1:\"5\";s:5:\"width\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"height\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"status\";s:1:\"1\";}"},{"setting":"a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:17:\"Featured Products\";s:7:\"product\";a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"145\";i:1;s:3:\"146\";}s:5:\"limit\";s:1:\"4\";s:5:\"width\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"height\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"status\";s:1:\"1\";}"}]}
```

Comment: `json_decode` can help  you in that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: However you've ended up with serialized PHP inside JSON, please reconsider.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, no, it is not. You didn't even try to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mix of JSON and PHP-serialized data.

```
<?php
$string = '{"num_rows":2,"row":{"setting":"a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Featutred\";s:7:\"product\";a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"145\";i:1;s:3:\"148\";}s:5:\"limit\";s:1:\"5\";s:5:\"width\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"height\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"status\";s:1:\"1\";}"},"rows":[{"setting":"a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Featutred\";s:7:\"product\";a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"145\";i:1;s:3:\"148\";}s:5:\"limit\";s:1:\"5\";s:5:\"width\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"height\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"status\";s:1:\"1\";}"},{"setting":"a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:17:\"Featured Products\";s:7:\"product\";a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"145\";i:1;s:3:\"146\";}s:5:\"limit\";s:1:\"4\";s:5:\"width\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"height\";s:3:\"200\";s:6:\"status\";s:1:\"1\";}"}]}';    

$dataObject = json_decode($string);
foreach($dataObject->rows as $row){

    $productData = unserialize($row->setting);
    print_r($productData);

}
```

Will result in

```
Array
(
    [name] => Featutred
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => 145
            [1] => 148
        )

    [limit] => 5
    [width] => 200
    [height] => 200
    [status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [name] => Featured Products
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => 145
            [1] => 146
        )

    [limit] => 4
    [width] => 200
    [height] => 200
    [status] => 1
)
```

*NOTE*: There is no error checking in code above, since it is written for your particular example. If you are not sure that your input data is correct (that is usual), you need to check if JSON is ok, object is object and also has needed properties, etc.