# Decoding Json file results blank page

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode below JSON file contents with php.

```
"notification": {/* code related to notification */ },
"HOME_SCREEN": 
    {
        "Phone": 
        {
            "position": 1 ,                         
            "list": 
            [
                {
                    "position": 1,
                    "productID": "105"

                }
            ]
        },
    },
"notify": { /* code related to notify */},
```

I followed links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php) & tried as below. but its giving blank page....

```
$string = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($json_a as $Phone => $person_a)
 {
   echo isset($person_a['position']);
 }
```

Also tried as :

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("test.json");
$decoded = json_decode($json_string);
$comments = $decoded->data[0]->comments->data;
foreach($comments as $comment){
   $position = $comment->position;   
   echo $comment['position'];
}
```

and below:

```
$url = 'http://url.com/test.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json as $i){
    echo $i['position'];
}
```

**Edit**

checked [Json file](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com:81/test.json) online, its **valid** json , same json file in better view  : https://pastebin.com/mUEpqfaM

Comment: Have you just tried using `print_r` in the decoded json? Like that, you can check the parsed structure and increment the values from there.

Comment: What does your json look like exactly? What you have posted is not valid json.

Comment: For validating json, you can use something like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @FirstOne when i tried i got result as [here](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com:81/home.php)

Comment: @Kaddath when i tried `json_decode` , i got result as [link2](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com:81/home2.php)

Comment: @jeroen its valid json file , tested online = > [link3](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com:81/test.json)

Comment: @Chris checked it, its valid json [link3](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com:81/test.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing more you can/should do with decoding of JSON file.

As written in [php documentation for json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you are using `$assoc = true` so you're converting whole JSON file into associative array. It's up to you if you want to decode the JSON file into an *OBJECT* or *ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY*. Till this point, you have it correct.

For your understanding, the main difference is:

- *ARRAY*, you access values with `$json['notification']`
- *OBJECT*, you access values with `$json->notification`

I prefer *ARRAY*, as it's easier for me to navigate in and use `foreach` loops. As written in comments, you should check the structure of your decoded file, so you can understand how you can access values you're interested in.

Minimal code to do that is

```
$string = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

echo "<pre>";
  print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

Let's say you want to access the **position** in your **$json** array for **HOME_SCREEN / Phone > list**, for that, you need to use this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($json['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone']['list'] as $item) {
  echo $item['position'];
}
```

Comment: thanks, in browser i need to give `edit option` for `position` value and once i click on `save button` position value should change & save file in json format, is this possible ?

Comment: please tell why this is not working : `foreach ($json['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone'] as $item) 
{
 

  echo $item['position'];` }?

Comment: That is because you don't have such a structure. When looping through `list`, you are accessing `$json['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone']['list'][0]['position']` (see that zero there?). In `$json['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone']` the position is directly in the `$item` variable as you're directly on that value, not on an array containing values like in `list`

Comment: then is there any way to display values of `['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone']` ? i need these values : `"HOME_SCREEN":{
      "Phone":{
         "position":1,
         "isImage":"false"
         
         },` , full file : https://pastebin.com/cSn6eZeG

Comment: As I wrote, for that, simply `echo $item;` will display it. You can always check what is inside the variable by using `var_dump($item);` and that way you will see if you have a desired value there (value of position) or you have an array that has key->value (item['position'])

Comment: thanks, can you help me how to get values of `price :R` & `price :D` here : `"HOME_SCREEN":{
      "Phone":{         
         "price":{
            "R":549,
            "D":15
         },`

Comment: without loops, it's `$json['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone']['price']['R']` and `$json['HOME_SCREEN']['Phone']['price']['D']` .. in loop, that would need some more code, checking if it's string or array, what key is there etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161606/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-moped).