# PHP Get Specific Data from JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to fetch the `icons -> icon` value from this:

```
{"revision":5,"patchRevision":121,"formatVersion":4,"npTitleId":"CUSA00744_00","console":"PS4","names":[{"name":"Minecraft: PlayStation®4 Edition"}],"icons":[{"icon":"http://gs2-sec.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2-sec/appkgo/prod/CUSA00744_00/5/i_30fd62592fcf63ded20a048269062dff3113c438d32414b9da63dde6f3d86f7c/i/icon0.png","type":"512x512"}],"parentalLevel":4,"pronunciation":"http://gs2-sec.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2-sec/appkgo/prod/CUSA00744_00/5/i_30fd62592fcf63ded20a048269062dff3113c438d32414b9da63dde6f3d86f7c/i/pronunciation.xml","contentId":"UP4433-CUSA00744_00-MINECRAFTPS40000","backgroundImage":"http://gs2-sec.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2-sec/appkgo/prod/CUSA00744_00/5/i_30fd62592fcf63ded20a048269062dff3113c438d32414b9da63dde6f3d86f7c/i/pic0.png","bgm":"http://gs2-sec.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2-sec/appkgo/prod/CUSA00744_00/5/i_30fd62592fcf63ded20a048269062dff3113c438d32414b9da63dde6f3d86f7c/i/snd0.at9","category":"gd","psVr":0,"neoEnable":1}
```

Using this:

`$tmdb['icons']['icon']`

But it doesn't seem to return the right value, All it returns is `null`. I've tried doing `$tmdb['icons']->icon` aswell as suggested in some tutorials, but that didn't seem to do the trick either.

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: do `var_dump($tmdb)` and post the output

Comment: How many times will we see this same unresearched question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access it using (if the second parameter for `json_decode()` is `true`):

`$tmdb['icons'][0]['icon']`

as you can see:

```
"icons": [
    {
      "icon": "http://gs2-sec.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2-sec/appkgo/prod/CUSA00744_00/5/i_30fd62592fcf63ded20a048269062dff3113c438d32414b9da63dde6f3d86f7c/i/icon0.png",
      "type": "512x512"
    }
  ],
```

is an array, `[]` means an array

If `json_decode()`'s second parameter is not set to `true`, you can access it like this:

```
$tmdb->icons[0]->icon
```

This is assuming that you have already decoded your JSON data, if you didn't you have to like this:

`$data = json_decode($your_json)`

Comment: Correct, if the JSON is decoded with `json_decode(..., true)`.

Comment: Yes, I'll add a clarification for both cases