# How to display a single result from a JSON Result

Tags: php, json, curl

Hello i am very new to coding in php and using curl so keep that in mind when replying. I am trying to get a single element from a JSON Object and cant figure out how to do it i so far have written this which isn't much but cant seem to get it to work any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$curl=curl_init("https://api.brawlhalla.com/legend/3/?api_key=KEY");
$resp=curl_exec ($curl); 
$jsonObj=json_decode($resp);
echo $jsonObj->legend_id;
curl_close($curl);
```

This is what the json object looks like

```
{ "legend_id": 3, "legend_name_key": "bodvar", "bio_name": "B\u00f6dvar", "bio_aka": "The Unconquered Viking, The Great Bear", "bio_quote": "\u201cI speak, you noble vikings, of a warrior who surpassed you all. I tell of a great bear-man who overcame giants and armies, and of how he came to leave our world and challenge the Gods.\u201d", "bio_quote_about_attrib": "\"-The Saga of B\u00f6dvar Bearson, first stanza\"", "bio_quote_from": "\"Listen you nine-mothered bridge troll, I'm coming in, and the first beer I'm drinking is the one in your fist.\"", "bio_quote_from_attrib": "\"-B\u00f6dvar to Heimdall, guardian of the gates of Asgard\"", "bio_text": "Born of a viking mother and bear father, B\u00f6dvar grew up feared and mistrusted by his own people.\nB\u00f6dvar's first nemesis was the terrible giant bear Grothnar, his own brother. By defeating Grothnar in a battle that lasted seven days, B\u00f6dvar chose to side with humanity and became the protector of the people of the north. He led his Skandian people against the Witch Queen of Helheim, slew the White Dragon Sorcerer, and lived the life of an all-conquering hero.\nAfter he single-handedly ended the Giant Wars by trapping the fire giant king in his own volcano, B\u00f6dvar sensed his work was done. But he felt doomed to never be taken by the Valkyries to Valhalla because he could never manage to be defeated in battle. So he travelled to Asgard himself, broke down the doors, and let himself in.\nValhalla is everything B\u00f6dvar hoped - an endless reward of feasting and fighting, with himself among its greatest champions.", "bot_name": "B\u00f6tvar", "weapon_one": "Hammer", "weapon_two": "Sword", "strength": "6", "dexterity": "6", "defense": "5", "speed": "5" }
```

Comment: You need to look at json_decode. Get an array. This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Missed the option that controls printing response or return that into variable. Use following piece of code below curl_init:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

**CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER** -    TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.

Read More about it [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)