# i can't parse this JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a [JSON](http://noticiasjson.blob.core.windows.net/json3/super/map_minuto.json)
object, but I can't parse it in PHP.

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://noticiasjson.blob.core.windows.net/json3/super/map_minuto.json");
$json = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($json);
```

The **result** is **null**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php

Comment: I believe you may be facing a character encoding issue. If you `var_dump($data)` it's a string, but a string full of total gibberish.

Comment: @RedaMeskali that link doesnt cover his actual issue. Which is, "unexpected character" (as reported by `echo json_last_error_msg();`). Its not valid JSON.

Comment: Are you sure you have [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled as per the notes section of [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: I ran the json url though some online validators.  The json fails.

Comment: @JasonK Seemed ok to me when I validated it :s

Comment: If you copy the file content and assign it as the value of `$data`, then all is fine (_"No error"_). But, if you fetch the content directly from the URI, then it looks weird (_"Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"_). So @RyanKozak is right: Your remote content is not properly encoded.

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip` is not supported by plain fopen http wrappers.