# I need a foreach (json) for params

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have this json file:[image: json file] and I would like to get all the title so my code is: **var_dump($json['results'][0]['title']);** but it getting just one title, I know I need to do a foreach but I don't know how :( so if you could help me that will be great ! Thanks

Comment: `foreach ($json['results'] as $result) echo $result['title'];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is coming back as an array with item's inside of it. This mean's you'll need to loop through this JSON and print each item;

```
foreach($json['results'] as $movie) {
    echo $movie['title'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a another problems I want for every film in the json file a new thing to appears in my page so I did this code and this appear :( @Darren

I think I need to to a while ? but i dont know how https://imgur.com/a/kffIebu

Comment: You need to modify your HTML that you put in there to replace the image and description as you require.

Comment: modify what pls

Answer (score 1):

You will want to loop through all of the JSON results objects and echo or store the 'title' value;

```
foreach ($json['results'] as $object) {
    //Option 1
    echo $object['title'];

    //Option 2
    array_push($titles, $object['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the variable $json contains your data, I see two equivalent options in order to iterate trough the array

1. Using for

   ```
   for($index = 0; $index < count($json['results']); $index++) {
       echo $json['results'][$index]['title'] . "\n";
   }
   ```
2. Using foreach

   ```
   foreach($json['results'] as $movie) {
       echo $movie['title'] . "\n";
   }
   ```