# Converting json to csv returns array,array

Tags: php, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a json file to csv but only the text "array,array" gets printed in the csv file. I'm guessing this is because multiple arrays get returned but as a noob i dont know how to fix this.

```
 <?php

 $jsonString = file_get_contents("data.json");

//Decode the JSON and convert it into an associative array.
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$jsonDecoded = $jsonDecoded;


//Give our CSV file a name.
$csvFileName = 'example.csv';

//Open file pointer.
$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');

//Loop through the associative array.
foreach($jsonDecoded as $row){
    //Write the row to the CSV file.
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

//Finally, close the file pointer.
fclose($fp);


print $jsonDecoded;
echo json_last_error_msg();

?>
```

The json looks like this, contains multiple records and should be printed each on a row.

```
{"data":[{"ID":4,"UUID":"53F","A schematic overview of your activities":"Yes","Q1_1-1":"To some extent","Q1_1-2":"To some extent","Q1_1-3":"To some extent","Question 1_2":"Yes","Q1_2-1":"Yes","Q1_2-2":"To some extent","Q1_2-3":"No","Q1_2-4":"Yes","Q1_2-5":"To some extent","Q1_2-6":"Yes","Question 1_3":"Yes","Q1_3-1":"Yes","Q1_3-2":"To some extent","Q1_3-3":"To some extent","Q1_3-4":"No","Q1_3_5":"Yes","Question 2":"To some extent","Q2_2":"To some extent","Q2_3":"To some extent","Q2_4":"To some extent","Question 3":"No","Q3_2":"No","Q3_3":"To some extent","Q3_4":"Yes","Question 3_2":"Yes","Q3_2-2":"Yes","Q3_2-3":"To some extent","Question 3_3":"No","Q3_3-2":"To some extent","Q3_3-3":"Yes","Q3_3-4":"To some extent","Question 3_4":"Yes","Q3_4-2":"To some extent","Q3_4-3":"To some extent","Q3_4-4":"To some extent","Question 3_5":"Yes","Q3_5-2":"To some extent","Q3_5-3":"Yes","Q3_5-4":"Yes","Q3_5_5":"To some extent","Q3_5-6":"To some extent","Question 3_6":"Yes","Q3_6-2":"Yes","CreatedAt":"2019-08-14T10:38:07.033Z","CreatedBy":"qqq","UpdatedAt":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"CreatedByID":20,"UpdatedByID":null},{"ID":5,"UUID":"2D40","A schematic overview of your activities":"Yes","Q1_1-1":"To some extent","Q1_1-2":"To some extent","Q1_1-3":"Yes","Question 1_2":"Yes","Q1_2-1":"To some extent","Q1_2-2":"No","Q1_2-3":"To some extent","Q1_2-4":"Yes","Q1_2-5":"Yes","Q1_2-6":"To some extent","Question 1_3":null,"Q1_3-1":null,"Q1_3-2":null,"Q1_3-3":null,"Q1_3-4":null,"Q1_3_5":null,"Question 2":null,"Q2_2":null,"Q2_3":null,"Q2_4":null,"Question 3":"No","Q3_2":"To some extent","Q3_3":"To some extent","Q3_4":"To some extent","Question 3_2":"Yes","Q3_2-2":"To some extent","Q3_2-3":"Yes","Question 3_3":"Yes","Q3_3-2":"No","Q3_3-3":"To some extent","Q3_3-4":"Yes","Question 3_4":"Yes","Q3_4-2":"To some extent","Q3_4-3":"Yes","Q3_4-4":"Yes","Question 3_5":"No","Q3_5-2":"To some extent","Q3_5-3":"To some extent","Q3_5-4":"Yes","Q3_5_5":"To some extent","Q3_5-6":"To some extent","Question 3_6":"Yes","Q3_6-2":"To some extent","CreatedAt":"2019-08-19T13:48:22.770Z","CreatedBy":"qqq","UpdatedAt":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"CreatedByID":20,"UpdatedByID":null}]}
```

Comment: You can see the issue with `print_r($jsonDecoded);`

Comment: `$jsonDecoded = $jsonDecoded;` Yes ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to refer to the `'data'` key.

```
foreach($jsonDecoded['data'] as $row){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fputcsv.php

```
 $jsonString = file_get_contents("data.json");

//Decode the JSON and convert it into an associative array.
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$list= $jsonDecoded;

file = new SplFileObject('example.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    $file->fputcsv($fields);
}
```