# I have a json strign row how to count columns

Tags: json, laravel

My question is: I have a JSON string row like:

```
{
    "id": 15,
    "description":"new product",
    "pic1": "15682078931.jpg",
    "pic2": "15682078632.jpg",
    "pic3": "15682078633.jpg",
    "pic4": "15682078634.png",
    "pic5": "15682078635.jpg"
}
```

And I want to print like:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($product as products)
{
   $i++;
   $pics = $product->pic.[$i];
   echo $pics;
}
```

How could I do, I didn't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong JSON string. You were missing double quote `"` before `id`

```
<?php 
$json = '{"id":15,"description":"new product","pic1":"15682078931.jpg","pic2":"15682078632.jpg","pic3":"15682078633.jpg","pic4":"15682078634.png","pic5":"15682078635.jpg"}';


$product = json_decode($json);

echo $product->pic1;
 ?>
```

Here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/CVMOM)

Comment: hey there, How to append an image using jquery to Div element through ajax in laravel. like:-
<img class="round-top" src=" asset('/images/logo/'.$arrivals[$pic])" alt="Card image cap">
It shows this type of error ;-
Use of undefined constant images - assumed 'images' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: `src=" asset('/images/logo/'.$arrivals[$pic])"` or `src=" {{asset('/images/logo/'.$arrivals[$pic]) }}"`?

Comment: echo it `/images/logo/'.$arrivals[$pic]` somewhere

Comment: but without attach asset() method how to access

Comment: You can do with both to check what actually is coming out from it

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the problem I solved

```
 for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)    
    {
         $pic = 'pic'.$i;
         $new .= '<div class="item mt-5 mx-1">
                      <div class="z-depth-2 mb-2 mx-height">
                        <img class="round-top" src=" asset('/images/logo/'.$arrivals[$pic])" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                  </div>';
            // echo $arrivals[$pic];
        }
```

> This problem is solved but the new problem is how to append an image
>   in JSON like:

```
<img class="round-top" src=" asset('/images/logo/'.$arrivals[$pic])" alt="Card image cap">
```

.It shows this type of error:-

Use of undefined constant images - assumed 'images' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)