# How can I use swedish letters with json_encode() in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, json

I have an array like this, which I json encode:

```
    $regularArray = array(      
        array( "label" => "Hello World", "value" => 1 ),
        array( "label" => "Hej Världen", "value" => 2 )
    );

    $jsonArray = json_encode( $regularArray );
```

("Hej världen" means hello world in swedish) But when I print `$jsonArray` I get this:

```
[{"label":"Hello World","value":1},{"label":null,"value":2}]
```

Why is the label `null` for the second item in the array? I know it has to do with the word "Världen" since it contains a non-standard letter. How can I get around this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When I run that code I get `[{"label":"Hello World","value":1},{"label":"Hej V\u00e4rlden","value":2}]`

Comment: @Quentin Yep. As some of the guys said below I changed the encoding of my files to UTF8. Then I got the same as you. Still a problem. How do I get around it?

Comment: — Why is it a problem? `\u00e4` is JSON for `ä`

Comment: @Quentin Because I don't want to preg_replace() just to make the characters print out normally..

Comment: JSON is a structured data format. It sounds like you are trying to use it as a display format. Don't do that, it isn't what it is designed for.

Comment: Hello, here is a question with another php solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268810/encoding-troubles-one-format-to-another/39364497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function only works with UTF-8 encoded data. You may change your input array data to UTF-8.

Encode the input array data using [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and decode it whenever you need the data using [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

```
<?php
   $regularArray = array(      
        array( "label" => "Hello World", "value" => 1 ),
        array( "label" => "Hej Världen", "value" => 2 )
    );
    $regularArray[1]['label'] = utf8_encode( $regularArray[1]['label']);
    echo $jsonArray = json_encode( $regularArray );
    $data = json_decode($jsonArray, true);
    $data[1]['label'] = utf8_decode($data[1]['label']);
    print_r($data);

?>
```

Output:-

```
[{"label":"Hello World","value":1},{"label":"Hej V\u00c3\u00a4rlden","value":2}]
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Hello World
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Hej Världen
            [value] => 2
        )

)
```

I made a [Test Page](http://codepad.org/2b5cUhmS), it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` expects the input to be utf-8. Save your file as utf-8.

Comment: Ok. But then it prints out "Hej V\u00e4rlden" instead.

Comment: \00e4 is perfectly legit here. cf http://json.org/, a 'char' can be the utf-8 char or its \uxxxx representation. \u00e4 is the correct character as seen in http://unicode.coeurlumiere.com/